# Wifi Problem on 2007 imac running 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom, mac

Like the title says, I have been running 16.04 LTS on my 2007 iMac for the past week. When I first installed it, the Wifi was working well. It would drop connections every now and then, but I think that was mostly due to my internet connection.
  I just moved the computer to my new apartment, and now it says it is connecting to the wifi network, but I am unable to access the internet.  I know that the Wifi network is working because my other computers are working just fine.
  Under "Additional Drivers", it says that the Broadcom 802.11 Airport Extreme chip is being used, but if I type [lspci -v] command, then it states access denied under the same chip(I don't know if that is abnormal or not).
  Anyways, that is about the extent of my troubleshooting. Please let me know if you can tell what I'm doing wrong! Thanks in advance for any responses.

Edit: As requested, here is the output of the lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list command

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328](rev 03)
Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:0088]
  Kernel driver in use: wl
  Kernel modules: ssb, wl
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I have the exact same problem on my 2007 iMac. Everything worked fine with Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.